# What is the differences between xctl and link in cics in term of sending and receiving maps?

Tags: cics

What is the difference between XCTL and LINK in CICS in term of sending and 
receiving maps ?

I am not clear about the concept about how the above concept effects the way the sub programs are called in CICS. Please someone explain.

Answer (score 1):

[XCTL](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/commands/dfhp4_xctl.html) is like a **GOTO**, you transfer control from current program to the new program but there will be **no return** to first program, it will return to the program that linked to the first program (or CICS). See also http://www.mainframestechhelp.com/tutorials/cics/cics-xctl-statement.htm

[LINK](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.doc/dfhtm/topics/dfhtm4w.html?cp=SSGMCP_5.3.0%2F12-17-5-0) is the normal **call return** process, there will be a return to the calling program (Cics Return) from the *linked to program* (or one that it XCTL's to).

With regards Sending / receiving maps have you tried ???. After a Xctl you can certainly send and receive maps